# PowerApps: Convert multi-value person columns into collection? Split/Collect?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

Is there a method to take the contents of multiple multi-value person columns from SharePoint and convert it to one collection of individual values (one record per person) in PowerApps?

I believe I can leverage Split and Collect to achieve this, but am having trouble with the exact syntax to follow. Or does PowerApps automatically convert these columns to a table anyways and I'm overthinking it?

For testing, I have a form showing 3 multi-value person columns I want to pull info from and combine into a collection. On clicking a button the action below is taken and results are shown in a gallery whose datasource is this collection.

```
ClearCollect(Participants, 
{Name: Value(Approver_DataCard1.DisplayName)}, 
{Name: Value(Reviewers_DataCard1.DisplayName)}, 
{Name: Value(Informed_DataCard1.DisplayName)})
```

So far, no luck. It creates 3 blank records. Even if it did work am not sure how I would pull additional user information; email, organization, etc.

[image]

Comment: Can't seem to find a way to get comma delimited output. There has to be a way to extract this data. If I use a listview control instead of a datacard I can also view the names, but I can't extract. Everything only returns the first item in a multi-value control.

Comment: In what format do you have the data in the inputs? It's blurred and it's hard to tell. It does not look like a User Picker Data card. What are you using for inputting user names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just managed to implement your example. Check it out:

**OnSelect** property of the **Collect** button:

```
Clear(Participants); 
Collect(Participants,DataCardValue19.SelectedItems);
Collect(Participants,DataCardValue20.SelectedItems)
```

Note: DataCardValue19 and DataCardValue20 correspond ot the "Reviewers" and "Informed" multiselect user pickers.

**Items** property of the **ListBox**:

```
Participants.DisplayName
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly!